# JCA (Resource Adapter) logging not working on Weblogic 12.2.1.2

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, slf4j, weblogic12c, jca

I am trying to solve an issue related to logging from an outbound resource adapter.

It runs on Weblogic 12.2.1.2, and has been written following the [Oracle J2EE guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/connectorexample001.htm).

I have setup the logging descriptor as per the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24971/weblogic_ra_xml.htm#i1078463), and when I deploy it weblogic creates a new empty log file in the location I have provided by the descriptor (as expected).

I have deeply followed the guide [Writing Messages to the WebLogic Server Log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13704/writing.htm#LOGSV151). I tried with **java.util.logging**, the **NonCatalogLogger** by the [mock JAR](https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=weblogic.logging.NonCatalogLogger) and **slf4j** so, all the log messages are printed to the *console* and into the *domain log file*, but **NOT** into the log file I have configured.

Could anybody tell me why?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why downvotes without a valid written reason?!

Comment: Some possible reasons for downvotes: [1] Your question may fall in this category of off-topic questions: [_"Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [2] If your problem relates to logging from your code (that's unclear to me) 
then show your code. [3] Your question is too abstract. You claim you have everything configured correctly, but instead of showing your configuration you link to articles on the web.

Comment: All the information are well explained in my post. It is absolutely a software related issue, but caused by a misconfiguration or a bug of Weblogic, so anybody who knows something about such issue does not need any code fragment. Usually, when I am not competent on such arguments simply I don't answer to the topic, instead of placing a downvote. Regards.

Comment: If the issue is "caused by a misconfiguration or a bug of Weblogic" it is clearly off topic for Stack Overflow regardless of how written your question may be, so the downvotes are legitimate. See [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I disagree with you, a misconfiguration or a bug is strictly related to a development blocking issue!

Comment: You are fundamentally misunderstanding why your question is off topic here. The fact that the issue occurs in your development environment is completely irrelevant. You asked _"Why downvotes without a valid written reason"_, yet choose to disregard/ignore any explanations for why you are being downvoted.

Comment: Thank your opinion, I think our argument can be friendly finish here. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot make weblogic working, so I had to find an alternative.

Here is my solution based on [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch).

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version> <!-- Depends on slf4j 1.7.25, conflicting with Weblogic 12.2.1.2 -->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version> <!-- Shipped with Weblogic 12.2.1.2 -->

    <adapter.config.file>/etc/logback-my-resource-adapter.xml</adapter.config.file>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**LoggerHelper.java**

```
package it.sisal.betting.sdg.adapter.sogei.logging;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer;
import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory;

    public class LoggerHelper {

        static {
            // https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

            System.setProperty(ContextInitializer.CONFIG_FILE_PROPERTY, "${adapter.config.file}");
        }

    public static final ILoggerFactory FACTORY = StaticLoggerBinderHack
        .getSingleton()
        .getLoggerFactory()
    ;

    public static LoggerContext CONTEXT = (LoggerContext)FACTORY;

}
```

**MyResourceAdapter.java**

```
public class MyResourceAdapter implements ResourceAdapter, Serializable {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerHelper
        .FACTORY
        .getLogger(MyResourceAdapter.class)
    ;

    private BootstrapContext context = null;

    @Override
    public void start(BootstrapContext context) 
        throws ResourceAdapterInternalException 
    {            
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("start(...)");
        } 

        this.context = context;
     }

     // And so on...
}
```